# Heatmap Renderer with Feature Layer

Tags: feature-layer, heat-map, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a set of data held in a backend database that I wish to render into a heatmap using esri. The data is dynamic based on users search and filters.

I'm creating the feature layer and applying the heatmap renderer but getting no luck with this, one thing I notice is that when I log the layer to the console the graphics geometry's are null whether this is the issue I'm not sure.

I've created a jsfiddle of where I am currently.

https://jsfiddle.net/sgdm9an7/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
featureSet.geometryType = "esriGeometryPoint"
```

check this sample, your code and sample different only featureSet.geometryType variable not implemented. so i check this code its run.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/fl_featureCollection.html

https://jsfiddle.net/jokcv8ph/

Comment: Without any context this answer is meaningless

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to provide more information about where/how to use your suggestion.  A brief explanation about why it's the answer would be useful too.

Comment: Just tried this within my jsfiddle and this did work. Thank you @emredelioglu! (Added the forked jsfiddle with this working into your answer!)